# angular 2 ngIf and ngSwitch for simple login

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, ng-switch

If `ngIf` is `false`, the whole html block won't be rendered. Is it the same for the false cases of a `ngSwitch`?

I want to have certain elements of a webpage not rendered unless the user is logged in.

And a followup question on performance:

let's say a particular html section is rendering a list of over 1000 forum threads using `ngFor`. If that section has a `ngIf == false`, will the loading speed improve? Does it mean it will execute the `ngFor` only then when `ngIf` becomes `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wrap the `*ngFor` with `*ngIf` then the `*ngFor` won't render and not execute at all when the `*ngIf` expression is `false` and this definitely will improve performance.
Modifying the DOM is expensive and should only be done if necessary.

`[hidden]="expression"` on the contrary will still update the DOM and render the element, only the `display` property is set to not display the element.

`*ngSwitch` works similar to `*ngIf` and won't render or execute `*ngFor` when the branch condition is false.

Comment: Thanks  Günter! Could you clarify on what you mean with "expensive"?

Comment: Needs lots of CPU resources and make the page rendering slow.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular-1.5
Respective DOM is not rendering if condition is not matching.
See AngualrJS Documentation. I don't think they changed this behavior in angular-2.